# How to crop a square from an image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, amazon-s3, lambda

This is a snippet of my lambda function on S3:

```
function tranform(response, next) {
  gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {

    var scalingFactor = Math.min(
        MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
        MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
    );
    var width = scalingFactor * size.width;
    var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

    this.resize(width, height)
        .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
            }
        });
});
},
```

This gave me an resized image. I would like to have and resized and cropped square image for a gallery preview. How can I do this?